# Accessing asp controls within a datalist

Tags: asp.net, datalist

How do you access an asp control within a datalist.  For example, I would like to, but currently cannot, access the HyperLink control or the ImageButton control by inline code, or in the code-behind file.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="altArtStyle">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTitle" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Default.aspx?order_by=title&direction=ASC" >

                        Title
                        </asp:HyperLink> <asp:ImageButton id="imgbtnTitle" src="/_images/hover-down.gif" runat="server"/>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.  For example, if you wanted to change the header at runtime, in one of the object bind events, you'd do something like for this datalist header, do a findcontrol on the hyperlink and with that reference, do this...

Comment: Could you give me a short code example?  I tried finding the control but got the complaint 'object reference not set to instance of object'.  Heres the code I used after binding the data set.  

Dim imgbtnTitle As ImageButton = FindControl("imgbtnTitle")
        If imgbtnTitle.ImageUrl = "/_images/hover-down.gif" Then
            imgbtnTitle.ImageUrl = "/_images/hover.gif"
        ElseIf imgbtnTitle.ImageUrl = "/_images/hover.gif" Then
            imgbtnTitle.ImageUrl = "/_images/hover-down.gif"
        End If

Comment: Looks like Jason's got it covered.  I'd only add that you might need to cast the control using CType.  Take a look at:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you need to call FindControl on the DataListItem object, in order to find the control on the specific row.  In your example, FindControl will only work on a header row, as in the following example:

```
Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header Then
        Dim btn As ImageButton = e.Item.FindControl("imgbtnTitle")
        If btn IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Do stuff here.
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

same you can do with labels and hyperlinks

```
private void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            ImageButton imgbutton = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("imgbtnTitle");
            imgbutton.ToolTip = "abc";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the asp controls inside the datalist by using the Datalist Item Data bound

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HyperLink TitleLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("lnkTitle");
    }

}
```